A question about angular momentum of electromagnetic system
I am quite confused about this consequence from Cohen-Tannoudji's Photons and Atoms: Introduction to quantum Electrodynamics. On page 46, he wrote

$$
\mathbf{J}_{\text {long }}=\varepsilon_0 \int \mathrm{~d}^3 r \mathbf{r} \times\left(\mathbf{E}_{\|} \times \mathbf{B}\right)
$$
where $E_\|$ is the longitudinal part of electric field, and $\mathbf{J}_\text{long}$ be the contribution of the longitudinal electric field to the total angular momentum of the system field + particles. Replacing $\mathbf{B}$ by $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}_{\perp}$ (since $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}_{\|}=\mathbf{0}$ ) and using the expression for the double vector product to transform $\mathbf{E}_{\|} \times\left(\nabla \times \mathbf{A}_{\perp}\right)$ yields\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J}_{\text {long }}=\varepsilon_0 \int \mathrm{~d}^3 r\left\{\sum_{a=x, y, z} E_{\| a}(\mathbf{r} \times \boldsymbol{\nabla}) A_{\perp a}-\mathbf{r} \times\left(\mathbf{E}_{\|} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}\right) \mathbf{A}_{\perp}\right\}
\end{equation}

Using the vector identity, I cannot reach the first term, and I wonder if there are more convenient ways to show the result (The system consists of \begin{equation}
\rho(\mathbf{r}, t)=\sum_\alpha q_\alpha \delta\left[\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_\alpha(t)\right]
\end{equation})
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J}_{\text {long }}=\sum_\alpha q_\alpha \mathbf{r}_\alpha \times \mathbf{A}_{\perp}\left(\mathbf{r}_\alpha\right)
\end{equation}

It follows immediately from the identities $$\mathbf{A}\times(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C})=\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{C})-\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B})$$
and $$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}=\sum_{a=x,y,z}A_aB_a$$
Here it is explicitly:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\times\mathbf{B})&=\mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}_\perp))\\
&=\mathbf{r}\times\left[\nabla(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\mathbf{A}_\perp)-\mathbf{A}_\perp(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\nabla)\right]\\
&=\mathbf{r}\times\nabla(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\mathbf{A}_\perp)-\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{A}_\perp(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\nabla)\\
&=\mathbf{r}\times\nabla(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\mathbf{A}_\perp)-\mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}_\perp\\
&=\mathbf{r}\times\nabla\left(\sum_{a=x,y,z}E_{\parallel a}A_{\perp a}\right)-\mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}_\perp\\
&=\sum_{a=x,y,z}E_{\parallel a}(\mathbf{r}\times\nabla)A_{\perp a}-\mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{E}_\parallel\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}_\perp
\end{align*}$$

Thanks for your help. I am still confused when the vector identities involve \nabla, from Jackson, the identity should be replaced by this one:\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\nabla}(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b})=(\mathbf{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}) \mathbf{b}+(\mathbf{b} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}) \mathbf{a}+\mathbf{a} \times(\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \mathbf{b})+\mathbf{b} \times(\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \mathbf{a})
\end{equation} Then I can not reach the same conclusion. B.T.W, $E_| $ is a longitudinal field, while $A_\perp$ is transverse, why their scalar product is not zero?

@user438676 Not all identities are applicable to all derivations. This identity may be valid, but that does not mean it is useful here (evidence: I have shown you a complete derivation that does not use it). Also, transverse/longitudinal refers to the divergence-free and curl-free components of the field. It does not imply anything about spatial orthogonality of those components at an arbitrary point.

This helps a lot, thank you!

@user438676 You are welcome, I am glad it was helpful
